# Advantages Page Rank has over TF-IDF

Tags: pagerank, tf-idf

Can anyone direct me to any academic papers regarding the comparison of PageRank and Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency. I've been searching all over and I just find papers on combining the two.

I need to find the advantages of Page Rank over TF-IDF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While PageRank and TF-IDF are both used for ranking, they are used for very different types of ranking.

PageRank assigns a score to a document based upon the documents it links to, and the documents which link to it. The score does not vary depending on the query used (i.e. it is a global ranking scheme).

TF-IDF is used to give a document a score based upon some query. The score changes based upon the query, and without a query there is no score.

The reason that you find lots of papers discussing combining the two, and not discussing their different advantages is because they are not really comparable in that way. It is very much a case of apples and oranges.